# Questions about Reichenbach's Principle and causes

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, causation, causality, being-and-time

Is "statistical dependences need to be explained causally" an accurate depiction of Reichenbach's Principle? (Rob Spekkens https://youtu.be/n8NRSPCekmI?t=1575)

Does one need to accept this principle to do science?

---

And by causal, I assume that rules out things like the block universe or the mathematical universe because relations are not causes. Just like for a patterned rug, one patch does not *cause* the next patch - it is the timeless/static patterns that describes the areas around the patch. Same for the block universe. Not causes, just relations.

But then how do we ever arrive at an actual causal story using mathematics? Isn't math always going to leave the door open as to whether anything is actually happening? Mathematical descriptions are essentially timeless relations are they not?

Does this principle actually work and make sense? Explained causally *how*, not mathematically...

Answer (score 1):

I can see how the saying, "correlation is not causation," might make you think that causation is not mathematical.  Nothing could be further from the truth.  Correlation is not causation, but statistics encompasses more than mere correlation.

[Judea Pearl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judea_Pearl)'s approach to causation is a successful one, and I'd recommend checking out [his book](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/book-toc.html).

In statistics, we can build *non-causal* models, and we can build *causal* models.  A typical Bayesian network, or a linear regression, is an example of a non-causal model.  What Pearl calls a "causal Bayesian network" is an example of a causal model.  An example of a causal model that is not probabilistic is [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).  What causal models have in common is that you begin with some initial conditions, and deduce immediate effects of those conditions, and then deduce effects of the effects, and so on.  Deduction in a causal model doesn't usually go "backwards" - it can go backwards, but there is a preferred forward direction from causes to effects, which lines up with the temporal order of events, with causes happening prior to effects.

So to find a "causal story," you build a model of a process, where the model is - by design - causal.  Then you check how well the model fits the observations.  If the model fits well, then you have a causal story.  You can try this for many different causal models to find the ones that fit the best without being too complicated (Occam's razor).

One way to distinguish causation from correlation is by looking at what kind of questions you can ask and answer.  If you have a non-causal model, you can ask and answer questions of the form, "If X had been observed to take the value x, what would the distribution over Y be?"  If you have a causal model, you can also ask and answer questions of the form, "if X had been *set* to the value x, what would the distribution over Y be?"  Pearl's causal Bayesian networks allow for this second kind of query.

Comment: I will take a look at Judea Pearl thanks. But if " distinguish causation from correlation" really always works, why are there people who believe the block spacetime model over the causal flow of time and becoming model. Isn't the point it's the same math, different stories - one causal one, one not.  Why does positing causality help us  if we just have  math and observed correlations. Why assume it? Since we can't tell the difference why do we need it.

Comment: @JKusin There's no reason why the "block model" can't be causal.  There's no operational difference between the "block model" and "causal flow" - it's just a difference in what mental picture you make, not a difference in what inferences you draw about events.  Conway's game of life has a causal update rule, but we can just as easily think of time as a "block" if we imagine stacking many timesteps of the game on top of one another.  The update rules are still causal if we do that.

Comment: @JKusin Non-causal rules are possible, but don't have anything to do with whether we think of "block time" or not.  An example of a non-causal rule would be the laws of physics describing what happens in a closed timelike curve (if they exist).  Or rules that don't involve time at all are non-causal, like the rules describing what a circle is or what the integers are.

Comment: But what about the rug example (I stole it from Harvey Brown a phil of physics)? The pattern of a rug has mathematical correlations but you would never say the left side of the pattern *caused* the right side. I don't feel you've addressed this key point. If I can have a mathematical description without causality, why gravitate toward causal models. Especially in reference to R's principle - why do we *need* causal explanations? I don't think causation is non mathematical, that's not quite my question. Now switch rug for spacetime

Comment: @JKusin Causal models allow us to evaluate the effect of an intervention.  If you want to know if a certain drug works to cure a certain disease, what you really need is a causal model, not a correlation. Causal models are more useful to guide our decisions if you can get them. The pattern of the rug is not causal because the rules that describe the pattern of the rug are not the kind of rules that will be captured well by a causal model. (Also the left to right direction across the rug is spatial, not temporal.  Whether a dimension is spatial or temporal does not depend on how we picture it.)

Comment: Why are you assuming we need a causal model, and not needing to uncover greater correlational structure? That is what we do in experiments, observe correlations. Why is this extra causality entering? Maybe I'm just turning this into a debate about realism and anti-realism though. Is the main reason we hold onto casulity for realism, like Spekkens says? Do you agree?

Comment: @JKusin Well, you can say that a causal model is a certain "kind" of correlational structure that is particularly useful for guiding actions.  After all, you do need to fit your causal model against the observations using standard Bayesian inference.  So yes, we need to uncover greater "correlational structure," but the particular type of correlational structure we most want to uncover for the purpose of deciding if a drug is effective, is the causal structure.

Comment: One more question. Does the causal model of the patterned rug allow one to make more correlations/predictions than the acausal model? To me it seems no. I would be fine with an answer like "because reality feels causative, that is why we gravitate toward those kind of explanations". I just want to understand if we are making assumptions/what they are when we posit causal explanations.

Comment: @JKusin Like I said, a patterned rug is not appropriate to be modeled with a causal model, because the rules constraining the pattern of the rug are not causal rules.  Does the causal model of the *drug* allow one to make more predictions than the non-causal model?  Yes.  It allows us to answer P(cure | do(drug)), the probability of a cure given that we applied the intervention of the drug, which is what we want to know.  The non-causal model only lets us answer P(cure | drug), the probability of a cure given that we observed the drug being applied, which is different and less useful.

Comment: Sorry to make you repeat yourself. I see your distinction in this case. But I just can't shake the feeling you've assumed (justifiably) a certain ontology, that there are causes. Math is the most global theory we have, and I don't believe it requires this kind of ontology. If we just have mathematical correlations (like positions and frequencies of dials and detectors from an experiment), it seems like I can go a different route, to an ontology of the rug and block spacetime. Why did the drug work? Not a cause, but "because" the rest of the pattern of the math/data gives the result.

Comment: I guess I am unsure of the relation of math to reality. I don't mean to make you resolve such a huge debate.

Comment: @JKusin causality *is* the pattern.  Just like in Conway's game of life:  there are mathematical rules describing how the state changes from timestep to timestep.  It's not *logically necessary* to have such rules, we can imagine universes with different rules where effects do not follow causes, but we observe in our universe, at least on Earth, that we do have this particular kind of rules.  (causal rules).  The laws of physics (at least on everyday scales and energies) describe change of state over time based on the previous state, and are thus causal.

Comment: Are there causes in the block universe?

Comment: @JKusin yes.  It doesn't matter if you view time as a block or not.  Causality is a matter of local structure in the block.  Some blocks would have causality, others would not, depending on what's happening along the time direction within the block.